# mysql. sql query. selecting

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a table with columns: id, artist, title, album.
i need to get rows with different values of pair (artist, title) and album

example:

i have now (result of my query):
**===artist ======= title ========= album**
*some artist1 === song title 1 === first album*
*some artist1 === song title 1 === second album*
*some artist1 === song title 1 === third album*

i need:
**===artist ======= title ========= album**
*some artist1 === song title 1 === first album*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group by as

```
select * from `table` group by title,artist;
```

It will return one row for one pair of title and artist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT artist, title
        FROM    mytable
        ) td
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable ti
        WHERE   (ti.artist, ti.title) = (td.artist, td.title)
        ORDER BY
                ti.artist, ti.title, ti.id
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This will return first `album` for a given `(artist, title)` in `id` order.

Change `ORDER BY` condition in the subquery to control which album will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out second and third album.  WHERE album NOT IN ('second album','third album')

It helps though if we can see schema.

Answer (score 0):

Which album you choose to show, depends on the ordering of albums. That ordering is not unique, but something like the following could produce what you are looking for:

```
SELECT artist, title, MAX(album)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY artist, title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GROUP BY artist title album
```